# GLSL instructions limit for different chipsets

Tags: mobile, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, shader

I'm porting an engineering application to all major mobile platforms.

It is important to confirm the VS/FS instruction limit for many of the shaders I'm gonna write.

I'm looking VS/FS instruction limit for the following chipsets.
Nvidia Tegra 2 -
Adreno 205/220 -
PowerVR SGX series -

Comment: What do you mean by "instruction limit"?  Shaders can be arbitrarily complex, but obviously the heavier the calculations you perform in the shader, the slower it will run.  All that the manufacturers can provide are best practices recommendations, and possibly shader profiling tools, because the interaction between shader instructions and performance is complex on desktop or mobile platforms.

Comment: @Brad Larson: Not true, both the number of individual instruction slots and the number of executed instructions (with loops) have limits on every flavour of OpenGL, depending on the generation of the underlying hardware. Unluckily, the ES shading language only says "as by the conformance tests", whatever that means. Since ES 2.0 is modelled after GL 2.0, you should be safe to assume 256 instruction slots and 65536 instructions as a minimum (probably more).

Comment: @Damon - Sorry, I may have overstated things, because the only limits I was aware of were the ones on uniforms, attributes, etc.  The point I was trying to make was that you'll run into practical performance limits in the complexity of your shaders before you hit any hardware ones, at least in my experience.  The mobile shader hardware isn't yet as powerful as what we're used to on the desktop, and I've seen >1 second frame rendering times with fragment shaders that only consumed 20-50 GPU cycles on the PowerVR series.  Some work may be required to port desktop shaders to a mobile device.

Comment: I'd like to know how you are able to determine count shader program instruction. How do you?

Comment: You can use a profiler such as Adreno Profiler that will analyze the shader's being used and output such meta information as the instruction count and so forth.

Comment: @BradLarson Who says the shader must run in real time?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a comparison of capabilities by shader version: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_shader_language#Pixel_shader_comparison

This is for HLSL but the same numbers should apply to GLSL equivalent versions.  I know this doesn't answer about the specific chipsets you mentioned, but you should be able to cross-reference their supported shader version against these capabilities.